# Find which int was minimum in PHP

Tags: php, min

I've got 2 integers.
I need to know which one has minimum value and get this value. Is there any pretty way (one function?) to do it? Now i'm doing it this way:

```
$foo = 5;
$bar = 7;
$min = min($foo, $bar);
if($min == $foo) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function does

Comment: not exactly. He wants to know which **variable** has minimun value. `min()` returns the **value**.

Comment: Use an associative array instead of 2 variables if you need to know the name of a particular piece of data?

Answer (score 2):

Use `min()` if you need to work with the lower value.

```
$min = min($foo, $bar);
print "min: $min";
```

And use a regular `if` if you simply want to do the comparison

```
if ($foo <= $bar)
{
    // $foo is smaller/equal
}
else
{
    // $bar is smaller
}
```